# stringstream: Why isn't this code returning 4?

Tags: c++, stringstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int get_4()
{
  char c = '4';
  stringstream s(ios::in);
  s << c;
  int i;
  s >> i;
  return i;
}

int main()
{
  cout << get_4() << endl;
}
```

The conversion is not working for me. If I write a character '4' or character array {'4','\0'} to stringstream and then read it out to int i, I don't get back the 4. What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: Why you use the `in` flag for an `in|out` stream?

Comment: Isn't it a bad idea to write to an input stream? Maybe you could try `stringstream s;` instead of `stringstream s(ios::in);`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you set the `stringstream` to input-only -- no output.

If you check the `fail()` bit after *trying* to extract the `int`, you'll see it didn't work:

```
 s >> i;
  bool b = s.fail();
  if( b )
      cerr << "WHOA DOGGIE!  WE BLOWED UP\n";
```

---

In your code, change:

```
stringstream s(ios::in);
```

to:

```
stringstream s;
```